# iOS 10 UILabels -> 1 UIView -> Loop through with Animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uiview, core-animation

I have 10 `UILabels`, maybe some `UIImageViews`. I want to display all these in 1 `UIView` with smooth FadeOut & FadeIn transition, one after the other.

I know putting `UIView` animations in a for-loop will not work as animations are done  asynchronous &  will not give proper effect. So the way normally I would do this is to chain `UIView` animation together. i.e. after one elements animation is complete begin the next one. For 3-4 elements the code looks ok. Like so -

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 
                      delay:0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut 
                 animations:^{ //do something with alpha here - first element } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 
                             delay:0 
                             options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut 
                             animations:^{ //do something with alpha here - 2nd element} 
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished){ ... }

                 }
```

But for 10+ elements it gets very messy. How would one go about doing this? Essentially I am creating a `UIView` with looping content, much like a widget.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edited with `NSTimer` instead of a loop.

`counter` is an ivar defined in the header.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    counter = 0;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.30
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(timerTick:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}

- (void) timerTick:(NSTimer *)timer{

    UIView *currentView = [self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:counter];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 
                          delay:0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut 
                     animations:^{ currentView.alpha = 1.0;}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{currentView.alpha = 0.0;}];
                     }
    ];
    counter++;
    if (counter >= [self.view.subviews count]) {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: this will stop after `i < [self.View.Subviews count]`. How do I keep it looping infinitely?

Comment: I think i've misunderstood you.
So you want that this keeps repeating infinitely?

Comment: Ah i understand. Use A NSTimer instead of the loop. I'll post an example code.

Comment: what i have is some 10 `UILabels` & some 5 `UIImageViews` I want them to keep looping one after the other infinitely or until a new dataset arrives... So my question is 1.how to keep looping infinitely? 2.Incase I want to refresh the data, how to do it? I mean animation might be going on right ? is this clear?

Comment: cool! thanks. This looks great. This takes care of my first problem. i.e.  looping infinitely. In case new data comes in & I have to re populate my data based on which the UI changes. Do I need to terminate NSTimer, then update the dataset & then start the NSTimer? or do i need to do something simpler? How do I ensure my app does not crash?

Comment: Actually, this should work dynamically. If you work without ARC, you should retain the `currentView` and release it in the `timerTick:` method in case it gets removed from his superview.