# UIView Core Animation not working in viewdidLoad method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, core-animation

I am new in IOS dev, using core animation in my project. i want my UIVIew default outside the main view and animate them on condition. when i call it in button method it work perfectly fine but when i call it in viewdidload nothing happen when program start.

Secondly i want to do this animation many times in my project Like this: 1 animate from right (Outside the screen) to left (Somewhere on screen), then 1 and 2 below them, then 1 2 and 3 and finally 1 2 3 and 4. can any one guid me how to do this? plz help

```
//1
//1 2
//1 2 3
//1 2 3 4


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[self animate];

}

-(IBAction)move:(id)sender
{  
[self animate];
}


-(void) animate {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
CGPoint pos;
pos.x = 241.0f;
pos.y = 20.0f;
mover.center = pos;
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: viewDidLoad is too early, you can call this inside viewWillAppear method.

Comment: try by calling the `animate` method from `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method and also use block based animation methods for animation

Comment: @Shan ViewDidAppear works perfectly fine :) Thanks Guys... can you guid me in my second issue...

Comment: @NasirKhan I think this link will help you for animation problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840261/ios-10-uilabels-1-uiview-loop-through-with-animation

Comment: @Student let me try these stuff... will tell you then...

Answer (score 0):

Please try to call  **[self animate];** this method on 1 second delay of view did load.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
    CGPoint pos;
    pos.x = 241.0f;
    pos.y = 20.0f;
    mover.center = pos;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.